# When submitting a multipart/form-data with ajax, file is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm with a problem when submitting a multipart/form-data with ajax.

HTML code:

```
<form id='form_foto' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   <input type='hidden' id='id_noticia' name='id_noticia' value='"+id_noticia+"' />
   <input name='foto[]' type='file' multiple />
</form>
```

jQuery and Ajax:

```
          $("#form_foto").submit(function(e){

                $("#form_foto").append("<br />Aguarde...");

                var formData = new FormData(this);

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/PortalGBD/services",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    async: false,
                    dataType: "multipart/form-data",
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function(resposta){
                        alert(resposta);
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault(); 
            });
            $("#form_foto").submit();
            self.close();
        }
```

And the request with a file input empty:

-----------------------------65942623427134 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id_noticia"

336 
-----------------------------65942623427134 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foto[]"; filename="" 
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

-----------------------------65942623427134--

Please help me with this problem. Thank you.

Comment: `contentType: false`!?

Comment: Yes, in all examples I've seen contentType: false.

Answer (score 0):

Please change one line from your code `var formData = new FormData(this);` to `var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);` and then check it.

When we create instance of FormData we pass form[0] instead form. It's mean actual form element, but not jQuery selector.

Comment: The problem is still happening, is submitting id_noticia input but not the file input.

Comment: Inside an event handler `this` is the actual element, not a jQuery object.

Comment: I'm creating a popup with a form in js, so `this` is the form.